# Can I use the .colliderect() without using Sprites? -PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I am trying to make a small endless runner and have most of the stuff done, the only thing left is the collision detection.
I know of the () function but can't get it to work. I probably just did it wrong but I'm out of ideas how to fix it.

Right now I have a Player Class like this:

```
class Player:
def __init__(self):
    self.size = (20, 40)
    self.color = white
    self.pos = [200, 330]
    self.shape_body = (self.pos, self.size)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.shape_body)
```

and an obstacle

```
class obstacle_ground1:

def __init__(self):
    self.pos = [1000, 330]
    self.size = (40, 40)
    self.shape = (self.pos, self.size)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.shape)
    self.color = white
```

(I have different ones, that's why there is a 1)
All obstacles are in a list and I wanted to check for collisions like this

```
def Check_if_dead(self):
    return self.rect.collidedict(obstacles[0].rect)
```

As a function of the Player class

But then I just get an typeerror:

> Argument must be a dict with rectstyle keys.

I know now that I could and maybe should have used sprites but I don' want to redo everything else so if you know a way around or just noticed a stupid mistake I made please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error message

> Argument must be a dict with rectstyle keys.

because you are using the wrong method.

If you want to test if 2 rectangles are intersecting, then you have to use the method [`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)  rather then [`pygame.Rect.collidedict`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidedict):

<s>`return self.rect.collidedict(obstacles[0].rect)`</s>

```py
return self.rect.colliderect(obstacles[0].rect)
```

The argument to `collidedict` would have to be a dictionary. The method would test if one of the rectangles in a dictionary intersects.
the argument to `colliderect` is a single rectangle and the method tests if two rectangles overlap.